# Linux equivalent for compact /c /s windows command?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line

I find the `compact /c /s` windows command really uselful for compacting ultra verbose traces/logs directories (which in my case, when debugging, can reach several GBytes in a few days).

Advantage : It keeps the visibility of the directory the same as if it was not compacted. It's transparent for explorer, powershell, and cmd.

Is there any Linux equivalent command, that would compress data, without putting the data in an archive file ?

Answer (score 2):

**Fast answer**:  when the file system support it:
`chattr +c nomefile` .

---

**More words** :

The one you are using is more a feature of *NTFS* file system. From one of the microsoft [page about it](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/compact.mspx?mfr=true)

> **Compact**
>   Displays and alters the compression of files or directories on NTFS
>   partitions. Used without parameters, compact displays the compression
>   state of the current directory.
>   ...
>   **Remarks**
>   - The compact command, **the command-line version of the NTFS file system compression feature**, displays and alters the compression attribute of files and directories on NTFS partitions. The compression state of a directory indicates whether files added to the directory will be automatically compressed. When you set the compression state of a directory you do not necessarily change the compression state of files that are already there.

There are many **file systems that allow that** e.g. you can check [fusecompress](https://code.google.com/p/fusecompress/) or [Btrf](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), [Zfs](http://zfsonlinux.org/) ...
The list changes in time:so you can start to search the word *"compression"* in the file systems list e.g. from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_systems) and  select what is better for you.

From [btrfs page of kernel.org](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression) you can read

> **Can I force compression on a file without using the compress mount option?**
>
> Yes. The utility **chattr** supports setting file attribute **c** that marks
>   the *inode* to compress newly written data.

Finally from `man chattr`

> A  file with the `c' attribute set is automatically compressed on the
>   disk by the kernel.  A read from this file returns uncompressed data.
>   **A write to this file compresses data before storing them on the disk.** 
>   Note: *please make sure to read the bugs and limitations 
>   section  at the end of this document*.